# How to bind a different DataTable to a DataGridView from user choice

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form with a `DataGridView` and 2 radio buttons. The user would select one of the button and will see a table populated in the `DataGridView` corresponding to his choice.

The first button works fine, the second gives me "Value type DataTable cannot be converted"

The text box is just a parameter for the query in the Dataset configuration.

The code I have is

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable1BindingSource
        Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.DataTable1, Val(Me.TextBox1.Text))
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable2BindingSource
        Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet2.DataTable2, Val(Me.TextBox1.Text))
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, please use the proper names for things.  You say that you have a "grid view" or a "gridview" when what you actually have is a `DataGridView`.  You haven't specified that this is for Windows Forms so when I read "grid view" I assume it's the `GridView` control from ASP.NET, which I have no experience with.  As a result, I very nearly didn't open this question, which it turns out I actually can help with.  It's not hard to use the actual names for the types you're using and doing so ensures that there can be no confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you are calling `Fill` on the same table adapter yet you pass a `DataTable` from a different `DataSet` in each case.  Each table adapter is associated with a specific `DataSet` and indeed a different `DataTable` so you'd have to be using a different table adapter in each case too.

Comment: Thank you very much, I should've asked if I can use the same Table Adapter for different DataTables and the answer is no, I'll use 2 different forms then because it wont fit on the same form. Thanks again.

Comment: Why would you need to use a different form just to add a second table adapter?  You certainly can use the same grid, so there's no issue with visual space.  You just have to unbind the grid and clear the columns each time, so that it can then recreate the correct columns for the new table.  By the way, if answer addresses your issue then please accept it as correct, so everyone can see that the question has been answered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that works perfectly. I appreciate your understanding as I'm new to this forum.